# Kendo DropDownList does not trigger cascade event

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have 3 `DropDownList`. The second works perfectly when I select value from the first one, Kendo automatically enables the second one and perform AJAX query. But when I select value from the second one the 3rd DropDownList is still disabled.

The code:

```
<script>
    function filterSchemas() {
        return { formGroupId: $("#FormGroupName").val() };
    }

    function filterRootElements() {
        return { shemaId: $("#Schemas").val() };
    }
</script>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.FormGroupName, "Form group")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(e => e.FormGroupName)
          .Name("FormGroupName")
          .OptionLabel("Select form group...")
          .DataValueField("Id")
          .DataTextField("Name")
          .Template("#= data.Name # (#= data.Version #)")
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              {
                  dataSource.Read(read => read.Route(RouteConfig.GetFormGroupNames.Name)).ServerFiltering(true);
              })
    )
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Schema, "Schema")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Schema)
          .Name("Schema")
          .OptionLabel("Select schema...")
          .DataValueField("SchemaId")
          .DataTextField("ShemaName")
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              {
                  dataSource.Read(read => read.Route(RouteConfig.FilterFormSchemas.Name).Data("filterSchemas")).ServerFiltering(true);
              })
          .AutoBind(false)
          .Enable(false)
          .CascadeFrom("FormGroupName")
          )     
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Root, "Root element")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Root)
          .Name("Root")
          .OptionLabel("Select root...")
          .DataValueField("RootId")
          .DataTextField("RootName")
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              {
                  dataSource.Read(read => read.Route(RouteConfig.FilterFormRootElements.Name).Data("filterRootElements")).ServerFiltering(true);
              })
          .AutoBind(false)
          .Enable(false)
          .CascadeFrom("Schema")
          )     
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that there is any element in the 3rd list corresponding to the 2 other filters?

Comment: not sure I understand you correctly, when I select value form the second dropdown the Data("filterRootElements") should be executed and Root dropdown's data source should load remote data from controller, but nothing is happening.

Comment: What I suggested is that the query was executed but returns nothing... But I have then seen in your code that you have put in your filter : `$("#Schemas").val()` as though in your code, the 2nd DDL is named `Schema` (without an "s" at the end) : is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that also right now and changed it to 'Schema', but it is still the same behavior, nothing is happening. also if I cascade 3rd DDL from the first everything works fine (CascadeFrom("FormGroupName"))

Comment: That is strange if you can filter your 3rd DDL on 2 distinct sort of data (FormGroupName and Schema)... Are you sure your code filters correctly on the schema in your controller action?

Comment: I mean if I cascade 3rd DDL from FormGroupName the js filterRootElements is executed and ajax call is performed

Comment: I ran into this same problem and it was a really lame mistake on my part: the results I was returning had some duplicate ID values. I suggest testing again using BindTo() on the parent with the value in BindTo being a hard-coded anonymous type to see if that works (new [] { new { ID = 1, Name = "Test" } }). If it does work, it is a data issue.